# Is $\partial^2_{xy}(x,y)$ continuous?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Let  $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{x^3y}{x^2+y^2} & \text{if $(x,y)\neq0$} \\ 0 & \text{if $(x,y)=0$} \end{cases}$$

I've to show that :
     $$\partial^2_{xy}(0,0)=1\neq\partial^2_{yx}(0,0)=0$$ and also show that $\partial^2_{xy}(x,y)$ is not continuous at $0$ ?

I'm not getting the correct answer for $\partial^2_{xy}f(0,0)$ and $\partial^2_{yx}f(0,0)$..also don't know how to check  $\partial^2_{xy}(x,y)$ is not continuous.

can anyone just explain this to me..thanks in advance

Comment: By $\partial^2_{xy}(0,0)$ you mean $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f\right)(0,0)$?

Comment: @konewka yes,exactly...

Comment: Then I agree with one of the derivatives, but can't find the other. But $\partial^2_{yx}(0,0)=0$

Comment: @konewka What is your value coming for $\partial^2_{yx}(0,0)$...

Comment: I'll write it out as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \partial_xf(x,y)=0$$
$$\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\partial_yf(x,y)=x$$
so $\partial^2_{xy}f(0,0)=0$ while $\partial^2_{yx}f(0,0)=1$.

By the contraposition of Schwarz theorem, this proves that the second derivatives of $f$ are not continuous in $(0,0)$.

Another proof that $\partial^2_{xy} f$ is not continuous in $(0,0)$, without invoking Schwarz theorem, is that $\partial^2_{xy}f(x,y)$ doesn't have a limit in $(0,0)$.

Comment: How do you take the conclusions that $\partial^2_{xy}$ and $\partial^2_{yx}$ are $0$ and $1$, doesn't seem to follow from your limits!

Comment: @konewka: the first line is $\partial_x f(0,y)$ which you can derivate with respect to $y$. Same for the second line.

Comment: @anderstood can you please provide me intutuion behind your first and second lines...

Comment: @anderstood if we compute simply, $\partial_{xy}^2f(x,y)$ and $\partial_{yx}^2f(x,y)$ ,then put $(x,y)=(0,0)$ ,will it be wrong..

Comment: @spectraa : just calculate the derivative w.r.t. $x$ and $y$, then take the limit. There is nothing special here. To your second comment, how would you "compute simply" in an other manner?

Comment: @anderstood first compute $\partial_yf(x,y)$ and then take its derivative w.r.t $x$ which gives us $\partial_{xy}^2f(x,y)$ and then compute its value at $(0,0)$

Answer (score 0):

As to $\partial^2_{yx}(0,0)$, we use the standard definition of the derivative.
We first calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f (0,0)$. We know: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x_0,y_0)=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_0+t,y_0)-f(x_0,y_0)}{t}$$
So in this case: $$=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(0+t,0)-f(0,0)}{t}=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{f(t,0)}{t}=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{\left(\frac{0}{t^2}\right)}{t}=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}0=0$$
So now, $$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f\right)(0,0)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y} 0=0$$

As for the continuity, it is not continuous. We know the derivative $\partial^2_{xy}$ is equal to $$\frac{x^6+6x^4y^2-3x^2y^4}{(x^2+y^2)^3}$$
We now take two limits, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}$ and $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}$. The limit for $x$ is equal to
$$\frac{0+0+0}{y^6}=0$$
and the limit for $y$ is $$\frac{x^6+0-0}{x^6}=1$$

So, the limit is path-dependent, so the $\partial^2_{xy}$ is not continuous!

Comment: thanks for help....do you have any idea about proving continuity of $\partial^2_{xy}(x,y)$??

Comment: Trying the same method gives me $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(0,0)=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} t^{-2}$, which isn't really defined, so I don't know about that one..

Comment: if suppose we have given $\partial^2_{xy}(0,0)=1$ then can we someway show continuity part....please if you can help tomorrow is my exam.....

Comment: For continuity you should check that $\lim_{(x_0,y_0)\rightarrow(0,0)} \partial^2_{xy}(x_0,y_0)$ is equal to 1, so you'll have to work out the derivative explicitly

Comment: As for that, I'm afraid the second derivative isn't contiuous in $(0,0)$

Comment: you are correct .my question says to prove it isn't continuous..how did you prove it

Comment: If you have the derivative, take two different limits: $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}$ and $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}$. This gives you two results, $0$ and $1$, so the limit is path-dependent and therefore the function is not continuous

Comment: yes, I do. Should I work out the two limits or can you take it from here?

Comment: I usually make mistakes so you please add it in answer so that I can accept the answer as well.....

Comment: This answer is incorrect in several ways. First, when you set $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0)$, you're only computing $f'_x$ at a *single point*, namely the origin, which is clearly too little information if you want to say anything about the *derivative* of $f'_x$. Second, $f(t+0,0)$ became $f(0,t)$, which became $t^3/t^2$ instead of zero as it should be...

Comment: @HansLundmark About the second one, that's just a typo, $f(t,0)$ for me is still $\frac{t^3}{t^2}=t$

Comment: No, it's $f(t,0) = \frac{t^3 \cdot 0}{t^2+0^2}=\frac{0}{t^2}=0$.

Comment: Oh wow, you're right.. Sorry for the stubbornness

Comment: OK, but that doesn't fix the other issue. You seem to argue that "the derivative of zero is zero", but that's only true if you differentiate a function which is *identically* zero. So far, you've only shown that $f'_x$ is zero *at the origin*, but you would need to show that it's zero along the whole $y$ axis.

Comment: Yes, you're right, this answer doesn't work...

Comment: You're on the right track, though! It's just that a little more work is needed before it's complete.